# "react-native-push-notification" package causing multiple dex debug error on android

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native

I have added the package "react-native-push-notification" and followed the manual iOS and android linking process. The app works perfectly on iOS but while running on android it shows the following error:

```
...
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I'm not sure what went wrong. I followd the process exactly as shown in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I added the wrong Google Play Service version (present in the docs).

```
compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0') {
  force = true;
}
```

I have changed it to:

```
compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0') {
  force = true;
}
```

In the `android/app/build.gradle` file. It fixes the issue.